# Trying to translate my Matlab routine for loading and preparing data to Python. Stuck in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, numpy, dataframe

this is my first post and I have been struggling with this problem for a few days now. The following code is a Matlab code that I usually use to load my data (.csv files) and prepare them for further calculations.

```
%I use this later on to predefine my array because they need to have to same length for calculations
maxind = 400; 

% i is given a vector (like test_numbers = [1 2 3]) I get from the user so I can iterate over the numbers of test specimen
for i = test_numbers 
    % Setup the Import Options and import the data
    opts = delimitedTextImportOptions("NumVariables", 4);
    % Specify range and delimiter
    opts.DataLines = [2, Inf];
    opts.Delimiter = ";";
    % Specify column names and types
    opts.VariableNames = ["time", "force", "displ_1", "displ_2"];
    opts.VariableTypes = ["double", "double", "double", "double"];
    % Specify file level properties
    opts.ExtraColumnsRule = "ignore";
    opts.EmptyLineRule = "read";
    % Import the data
    %Here I build the name and read the files/ the csv files are in the same folder as the main program.
    data_col = readtable(['specimen_name',num2str(i),'.csv'], opts);

    Data.force(:,i)=nan(maxind,1);
    Data.force(1:length(data_col.time),i)=data_col.force;
    Data.displ(:,i)=nan(maxind,1);
    Data.displ(1:length(data_col.time),i)=nanmean([data_col.displ_1,data_col.displ_2]')';
    Data.time(:,i)=nan(maxind,1);
    Data.time(1:length(data_col.time),i)=data_col.time;
    Data.name(i)={['specimen_name',num2str(i)]};
    % Clear temporary variables
    clear opts
end
```

Now I have to use Python instead of Matlab and I started with pandas to read my csv as DataFrame.
Now my question. Is there a way to access my data like in this part of my Matlab code or should I not use dataframes in the first place to do something like that? (I know I can access my data with the name of the column, but I got stuck by trying to refer my data like Data.force(1:length(data_col.time),i) in a new dataframe)

```
Data.force(:,i)=nan(maxind,1);
Data.force(1:length(data_col.time),i)=data_col.force;
Data.displ(:,i)=nan(maxind,1);
Data.displ(1:length(data_col.time),i)=nanmean([data_col.displ_1,data_col.displ_2]')';
Data.time(:,i)=nan(maxind,1);
Data.time(1:length(data_col.time),i)=data_col.time;
Data.name(i)={['specimen_name',num2str(i)]};
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.